# Some customers don't receive confirmation email

Tags: email

Some our our customers don't receive confirmation email.  Customers couldn't find email from their spam folder either.  We placed order to ourselves.  We didn't receive confirmation email for some orders.

Comment: You can try to open the cron.php in your browser. http://www.example.com/cron.php. E-mails are now sent by cronjob in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

If its a newer Magento release, remember that emails are sent via cron - not synchronously during checkout.

Ensure that you've got the cron configured properly on your store. If you do, then you should check the mail logs on the sending side to see if rejection is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue where mostly AOL and Yahoo accounts would not receive our messages. It turned out that those services were actively blocking our messages because our emails were coming from an arbitrary server.

We started sending out emails through MailGun and our deliverability increased to over 99%.

I'd recommend using an ESP (email service provider) to send your emails out.